# Como particionar pessoas em uma rede de amigos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Na sua turma, muitos estudantes são amigos. Vamos supor que dois estudantes que compartilham um amigo deverão ser amigos; em outras palavras, se os estudantes 0 e 1 são amigos e os estudantes 1 e 2 são amigos, então os estudantes 0 e 2 deverão ser amigos. Usando essa regra, podemos particionar os estudantes em círculos de amigos.
Para fazer isso, implemente uma função redes(), que aceite dois argumentos de entrada. O primeiro é o número n de estudantes na turma. Consideramos que os estudantes são identificados usando os inteiros de 0 a n – 1. O segundo argumento de entrada é uma lista de objetos de tupla que define os amigos. Por exemplo, a tupla (0, 2) define os estudantes 0 e 2 como amigos. A função redes() deverá exibir a partição de estudantes em círculos de amigos, conforme ilustramos:

```
>>> redes(5, [(0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4)])

Rede social 0    is {0, 1, 2}

Rede social 1    is {3, 4}
```

O que eu fiz:

```
def redes(n,lista_tuplas):
    rede = []
    rede2 =[]
    for i in range(len(lista_tuplas) - 1):
        while set(lista_tuplas[i]).intersection(set(lista_tuplas[i+1])):
            rede += set(lista_tuplas[i]).union(set(lista_tuplas[i+1]))
            break
        rede2.append(lista_tuplas[i])
    return rede,rede2


n = 5
lista_tuplas = [(0,1),(3,5),(3,6)]
print(redes(n,lista_tuplas))
```

O problema é que o código erra quando não há amigos em comum. A minha saída com os dados acima foi:

```
([3, 5, 6], [(0, 1), (3, 5)])
```

A primeira partição está correta mas a segunda não:
(3, 5)não deveria ter entrado na segunda partição!
Alguem conseguiria me ajudar a descobrir em que estou errando? 
Como corrigir?

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 2):

Criei uma solução usando [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) e [`for...else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)... Sim, esse `for...else` pode parecer bem estranho mas quando você entende para que serve pode ser bem útil, como é o caso...

Passos para a resolução do problema:

1. Criar um lista de grupos sociais;
2. Percorrer todos os relacionamentos recebidos como argumento;
3. Testar se algum dos alunos de cada relacionamento já está em algum grupo

   - Se pelo menos um dos alunos já estiver em algum grupo, adiciona ambos no grupo (como estamos trabalhando com [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) não haverão alunos duplicados no grupo);
   - Se ambos os alunos não estiverem em nenhum grupo, criar um novo grupo com ambos alunos.
4. Retornar a lista de grupos resultante

Código:

```
def redes(relacionamentos):
    grupos = []

    for rel in relacionamentos:
        rel = set(rel)

        for grupo in grupos:
            if grupo & rel:
                grupo |= rel
                break
        else:
            grupos.append(rel)

    return grupos
```

*PS: Eu ignorei propositalmente o número de alunos proposto no exercício pois este não faz diferença alguma no algoritmo, exceto talvez a validação das tuplas recebidas.*

---

## Explicação

#### [`for...else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Se você verificar a documentação encontrará o seguinte:

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement.

Tradução livre:

> Laços de repetição podem ter uma cláusula `else`; esta será executada quando o laço terminar pela exaustão do iterável (com `for`) ou quando a condição se tornar falsa (com `while`), mas não quando o laço é terminando através de um `break`.

Então o que fiz no meu código foi percorrer todos os grupos sociais que existem até aquele momento, e se algum dos alunos fizer parte de algum grupo, adiciona ambos ao grupo é sai do laço usando `break`, dessa maneira não cairá no `else`.

Porém se, após percorrer todos os grupos, os alunos ainda não pertencerem a nenhum dos grupos o Python executará o bloco `else` onde eu crio um novo grupo com os alunos.

Exemplos:

- `for...else`:

  Se iterar até o fim, entra no `else`:

  ```
  for i in range(5):
      print(i, end=" ")
  else:
      print("\n[O for executou até o fim sem interrupção]")
  ```

  Saída

  ```
  0 1 2 3 4
  [O for executou até o fim sem interrupção]
  ```

  Se for interrompido por um `break`:

  ```
  for i in range(5):
      break
  else:
      print("[Nunca ocorrerá por causa do break]")
  ```

  O código acima não imprime nada na tela pois não entra no `else`.
- `while...else`:

  Se iterar até o fim, entra no `else`:

  ```
  i = 0
  while i < 5:
      print(i, end=" ")
      i += 1
  else:
      print("\n[O while executou até o fim sem interrupção]")
  ```

  Saída

  ```
  0 1 2 3 4
  [O while executou até o fim sem interrupção]
  ```

  Se for interrompido por um `break`:

  ```
  i = 0
  while i < 5:
      break
  else:
      print("[Nunca ocorrerá por causa do break]")
  ```

  O código acima não imprime nada na tela pois não entra no `else`.

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-426276-6333-b)</sup>

---

## Código completo com exemplos mencionados na pergunta

```py
def redes(relacionamentos):
    grupos = []

    for rel in relacionamentos:
        rel = set(rel)        # transformo a tupla em set

        for grupo in grupos:
            if grupo & rel:   # se um dos alunos está no grupo
                grupo |= rel  # adiciona os alunos ao grupo
                break         # sai do for
        else:
            grupos.append(rel)

    return grupos


exemplos = [
    [(0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4)],  # Primeiro exemplo da pergunta
    [(0, 1), (3, 5), (3, 6)],  # Exemplo com erro na pergunta
]

print(f">>> redes({exemplos[0]!r})")
resultado_1 = redes(exemplos[0])
for i, grupo in enumerate(resultado_1, start=1):
    print(f"Grupo {i}: {grupo!r}")

print(f"\n>>> redes({exemplos[1]!r})")
resultado_1 = redes(exemplos[1])
for i, grupo in enumerate(resultado_1, start=1):
    print(f"Grupo {i}: {grupo!r}")
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-426276-6333)</sup>

Saída:

```
>>> redes([(0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4)])
Grupo 1: {0, 1, 2}
Grupo 2: {3, 4}

>>> redes([(0, 1), (3, 5), (3, 6)])
Grupo 1: {0, 1}
Grupo 2: {3, 5, 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, basta trocar o `while` pelo `if` já que seu teste lógico é excludente. Veja:

```
def redes(n,lista_tuplas):
    rede = []
    rede2 =[]
    for i in range(len(lista_tuplas) - 1):
        if set(lista_tuplas[i]).intersection(set(lista_tuplas[i+1])):
            rede += set(lista_tuplas[i]).union(set(lista_tuplas[i+1]))
        else:
            rede2.append(lista_tuplas[i])
    return rede,rede2


n = 5
lista_tuplas = [(0,1),(3,5),(3,6)]
print(redes(n,lista_tuplas))
```

Output:

```
([3, 5, 6], [(0, 1)])
```

Dito isso, acho que sua solução ainda tem alguns problemas:

1) Por que `n` é um argumento da função se você não usa?

2) Da forma como está seu código, só é possível identificar redes se os círculos com amigos em comum são adjacentes. Notou isso?

Comment: Preciso usar n? Como corrigir a questão 2?

Comment: Se não for usar "n", não precisa colocar como argumento da função. Tenho que pensar como resolve a segunda questão, mas é preciso verificar a interseção para todas as sublistas, não apenas para a sublista subsequente

Comment: se conseguir resolver, poste aqui por favor. Tentei bastante mas nao consegui, por isso a pergunta!Aparentemente, não é tão simples. Não entedi porque alguem negativou a pergunta...

Comment: a solução talvez seja simplesmente repetir os condicionais. Uma sequência de `elif`para cada uma das sublistas. Coloca tudo dentro de um `while`e saí dele quando acabar as sublistas. Não possso mexer nisso agora, mas se não conseguir aí, edito minha resposta depois