# re.error: bad escape \c at position 0

Tags: python, regex

Estou tentando fazer um `search` entre os arrays, e retornar o valor quando for correspondente, e quando não for.

```
import re

array = ['brasil','argentina','chile','canada']
array2 = ['brasil.sao_paulo','chile','argentina']

for x,y in zip(array,array2):
  if re.search('\\{}\\b'.format(x), y, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("Match: {}".format(x))
  else:
    print("Not match: {}".format(y))
```

Saída:

```
Not match: brasil.sao_paulo
Not match: chile
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>    if re.search('\\{}\\b'.format(x), y, re.IGNORECASE):  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
re.error: bad escape \c at position 0
```

Saída desejada:

```
MATCH: brasil
MATCH: argentina
MATCH: chile
NOT MATCH:canada
```

Comment: Luis, aparentemente você está tentando fazer uma busca no `array2` usando como termos de busca os itens do `array`. Só que se é isso mesmo o que você quer fazer porque estão usando `zip`? Não dá pra entender o que exatamente você quer ou que exatamente seu código tenta fazer. Aconselho fortemente a [edit] sua pergunta e explicar melhor suas intenções e dúvidas.

Comment: Eu gostaria que ele procura-se independente da ordem do array

Comment: E me retornasse o que existe em comum

Comment: por exemplo: Array 1 -> Line1 == Array2 -> All lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando a [resposta do @fernandosavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427556/112052) (que já explica porque usar `zip` está errado neste caso), segue uma explicação sobre porque sua regex falhou.

Vocè está usando `'\\{}\\b'.format(x)` para criar a regex. Dentro de uma string, `\\` é interpretado como o caractere `\` (já que a `\` é usada para sequências de escape, como o `\n` para designar uma quebra de linha, então para o próprio caractere `\`, usa-se `\\`).

Então quando `x` tem o valor `brasil`, o resultado é a string `\brasil\b`. E a regex intepreta o início da string como o [atalho `\b`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052), que indica uma "fronteira entre palavras" (*word boundary*, uma posição que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois, ou vice-versa). Ou seja, a regex procura apenas pela palavra "rasil" ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/NGmMpe/1/)).

Quando `x` tem o valor `argentina`, o resultado é a string `\argentina\b`. A sequência de escape `\a` corresponde ao [caractere BELL](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0007/index.htm) (um caractere de controle que [era usado para emitir um som](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) no terminal, embora [hoje em dia nem todos o façam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456167)). De qualquer forma, esta regex não busca pela palavra "argentina", e sim por um `\a` seguido da palavra "rgentina" ([veja](https://ideone.com/5Vc9iQ)).

E finalmente quando o `x` tem o valor `canada`, o resultado é a string `\canada\b`. Só que `\c` é uma sequência de escape inválida ([veja aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-22) a lista de sequências válidas), e a [documentação do módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) diz que o uso de sequências de escape inválidas [dá erro](https://ideone.com/SIdw5v).

---

Provavelmente você quis usar `\b` no início também, então bastaria fazer:

```
for termo in termos:
    r = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(termo))
    for palavra in palavras:
        if r.search(palavra):
            print(f'Encontrado {termo!r} em {palavra!r}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'{termo!r} não encontrado.')
```

Note o `r` antes de abrir as aspas (`r'\b{}\b'`). Isso indica um [*raw string literal*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708), dentro do qual o caractere `\` não precisa ser escrito como `\\`, o que deixa a regex um pouco mais legível. Agora as expressões serão `\bbrasil\b`, `\bargentina\b` e `\bcanada\b`, ou seja, todas são regex válidas.

Eu também compilo a expressão uma vez antes de sair buscando na lista de palavras, assim reaproveito a mesma regex no `for` interno (tudo bem que [existe um cache de regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514276), mas ainda sim acho que você não precisa recriar várias vezes a string dentro do *loop*).

Esta solução é quase igual [à do @fernandosavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427556/112052), com uma pequena diferença. Por exemplo, se tivermos algo como:

```
termos = ['brasil']
palavras = ['brasileiro', 'brasil']
```

Como a solução dele usa `termo.casefold() in palavra.casefold()`, ela encontra primeiro `brasileiro`, já que o termo `brasil` está de fato contido nesta string.

Já a regex `\bbrasil\b` só encontra a segunda palavra ("brasil"), pois a regex procura por `brasil` desde que haja um `\b` antes e depois (e como `\b` é a "fronteira entre palavras", a regex só encontra um *match* quando a palavra é exatamente "brasil").

Note também que ele usa `casefold()` para deixar a busca *case insensitive*. Para que a regex tenha o mesmo comportamento, você pode usar a [*flag* `I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I):

```
r = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(termo), re.I)
```

Ou ainda usar o próprio `casefold()` nas strings (tanto nos termos de busca quanto nas palavras sendo buscadas):

```
for termo in termos:
    r = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(termo.casefold()))
    for palavra in palavras:
        if r.search(palavra.casefold()):
            print(f'Encontrado {termo!r} em {palavra!r}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'{termo!r} não encontrado.')
```

A diferença se dá em alguns casos como o caractere `ß`, cuja versão maiúscula é `SS` ([veja](https://ideone.com/tOg5Oz)). Então uma busca *case insensitive* deveria encontrar tanto `ß` quanto `SS` ou `ss`. Só que usar a *flag* `re.I` não é suficiente para este caso, e somente com `casefold` funciona. Fica a seu critério, pois dependendo das strings que você busca, pode ser que não faça diferença (de qualquer forma, é bom saber que existem estas opções).

---

Por fim, ajustando as mensagens para o que você queria:

```
termos = ['brasil', 'argentina', 'chile', 'canada']
palavras = ['brasil.sao_paulo', 'chile', 'argentina']

for termo in termos:
    r = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(termo), re.I)
    for palavra in palavras:
        if r.search(palavra):
            print(f'MATCH: {termo}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'NOT MATCH: {termo}')
```

Saída:

```
MATCH: brasil
MATCH: argentina
MATCH: chile
NOT MATCH: canada
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, penso eu que respostas assim fazem a comunidade crescer, parabéns !!!

Answer (score 2):

```
termos = ['brasil', 'argentina', 'chile', 'canada']
palavras = ['brasil.sao_paulo', 'chile', 'argentina']

for termo in termos:
    for palavra in palavras:
        if termo.casefold() in palavra.casefold():
            print(f'Encontrado {termo!r} em {palavra!r}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'{termo!r} não encontrado.')
```

<sup>[Código rodando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-427556-6333)</sup>

Resultado:

```
Encontrado 'brasil' em 'brasil.sao_paulo'
Encontrado 'argentina' em 'argentina'
Encontrado 'chile' em 'chile'
'canada' não encontrado.
```

---

Para pesquisar se cada termo da primeira lista está em alguma string da sua segunda lista não é necessário o `zip`, pois você não precisa percorrer as duas listas lado a lado.

Um passo a passo seria:

1. Percorrer os termos de busca;
2. Para cada termo de busca, percorrer a lista de pesquisa;
3. Verificar se o termo de busca está contido nas strings pesquisadas.

Como você está testando apenas se `termo` é uma substring de `palavra`, não há necessidade de usar expressões regulares para isso (e sua regex não está correta de qualquer maneira), você pode converter a string para uma "caixa baixa especial" feita para comparação *case insensitive* que leva em conta algumas exceções do Unicode usando o método [`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold).

Apesar de parecer estranho, o `else` do código acima está correto pois estou utilizando um [`for...else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) (explico com detalhes [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/426276/6333)) para que o `else` só seja executado se o `break` não ocorrer.

*Dica construtiva: escolha nomes melhores para suas funções, classes e variáveis, assim fica muita mais fácil entender seu código.*

Comment: Eu só fiquei em dúvida se ele queria mesmo uma substring porque tinha um `\b` na regex, por isso achei melhor [responder com esta alternativa também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427608/112052), aí já ficam as 2 opções registradas. De qq forma, o +1 foi meu - ontem só votei mas estava com preguiça de escrever e só fui responder hj :-)

Comment: Você tem razão @hkotsubo, aquele é suspeito, porém eu escolhi ignorar a regex dele pois ela não faz sentido então não sei se a intenção do AP. Mas se o assunto é regex, acho excelente que você complemente com sua resposta. :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção e esforço, ficou muito boa sua respota

Comment: e vou seguir sua dica!!

Answer (score 1):

O problema estava no caracteter de escape `\`, sem ele seu código roda normalmente, mas não executa o que você quer.Usando a função `zip` não será possível fazer o teste para todas as entradas da `array2`, só para aquelas que têm o mesmo `index` da `string` de referência. Isso ocorre porque o `zip` faz uma combinação par a par. Veja:

```
array = ['brasil','argentina','chile','canada']
array2 = ['brasil.sao_paulo','chile','argentina']

for x, y in zip(array, array2):
    print(x,y)
```

Output:

```
brasil brasil.sao_paulo
argentina chile
chile argentina
```

Uma forma mais correta de construir seu código, portanto, seria:

```
import re

array = ['brasil','argentina','chile','canada']
array2 = ['brasil.sao_paulo','chile','argentina']

for x in array:
    if True in [bool(re.search(r'{}'.format(x), y, re.IGNORECASE)) for y in array2]:
        print("Match: {}".format(x))
    elif False in [bool(re.search(r'{}'.format(x), y, re.IGNORECASE)) for y in array2]:
        print("Not match: {}".format(x))
```

Output:

```
Match: brasil
Match: argentina
Match: chile
Not match: canada
```

Comment: Ainda sim não resolve o problema dele, pois se `chile` existir em `array2` o código mostrará 3 resultados, um positivo e 2 negativos... Ou seja, você terá: `Not match`, `Not match`, e só então você terá o `Match`.

Comment: Verdade. Vou editar agora para corrigir isso. Obrigado

Comment: opaa, muito obrigado por compartilha seu conhecimento!